# Alternative to FileReader() javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, filereader

I pretty much don't know how to come up with an altertnative to FileReader() in this situation.  I know that I can call if FileReader() is undefined to do something else, but what else is my option.

Thanks,

HTML -

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='#'>
<div style="height: 200px;">
<div class="droparea spot logoupload">
<div class="instructions"><img class="previewlogo" src="http://wmemusic.com/wme/admin/img/loginlogo.jpg" alt="Click or Drag image here to add login logo"/>
</div>
<input type="file" class="droparea spot logoupload" name="logo" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS -

```
.droparea {
                position:relative;
                text-align: center;
                min-height:100px;
                margin:0;
            }

            .droparea div, .droparea input {
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                right:2px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .droparea input {
                cursor: pointer; 
                opacity: 0; 
            }
            .droparea .instructions {
                border: 2px dashed #ddd;
                max-height:200px;
                height:auto;
                min-height:100px;
                overflow:hidden
            }
            .droparea .instructions.over {
                border: 2px dashed #000;
                background: #ffa;
            }


            #areas { width: 480px; }
            div.spot {

                margin: 5px auto;

            }
          .logoupload {width: 262px;
                min-height: 100px;
                height:auto;}
```

JAVASCRIPT -

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var imgHeight = $(".previewlogo").height();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('.previewlogo').attr('src', e.target.result)
        $('.droparea').attr('style', 'height:', imgHeight, 'px;')
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
```

I could use this to detect it: `if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined")`

Comment: I don't know of any other option; that's the whole reason the HTML5 file stuff was developed.

Comment: right but safari decided to not use it, and according to caniuse.com it doesnt look like there are any plans to include it

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL` is one alternative

Answer (score 0):

The fileReader was implemented in Safari v.6. For older versions use Post Ajax request to the simple PhP script that will echo back the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried any of them but there are plenty of polyfill for this specific issue, a good starting point is this list: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills under the 'File API' section.